# .NET6 で ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions 設定が機能しない

Tags: .net

非同期タスクの未処理例外でプロセスを終了させる設定 ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions が .NET6 で機能しません。
.NET Framework 4.8 では機能していたのですが、.NET6 に移行してから機能しなくなりました。

App.config に以下のように設定しています。

```xml
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

.NET6 では他の場所に設定するのでしょうか。それともこの設定自体廃止されたのでしょうか？

Comment: .NET Framework 4.x系以外に言及があるのがこちらの記事 [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException event...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3284137/9014308), [Using the UnobservedTaskException handler...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53891944/9014308) でした。他の文書はどれも.NET Framework 4.x主体の説明しか書いて無いので対応していないのかも。[<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions>](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/throwunobservedtaskexceptions-element), [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException...](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[互換性に影響を与える変更点](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/compatibility/)にはそれらしい記述は見つけられませんでした。本当に書かれていないのか、それとももっと抽象的な表現に含まれてしまっているのかはわかりません。

ソースコードを見ると、実際問題、この機能はなくなっています。

[.NET Framework 4.6.2の`TaskExceptionHolder`ファイナライザー](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/4.6.2/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskExceptionHolder.cs#L94-L150)にはいろいろと処理をしていて、最後に

```
// Now, if we are still unobserved and we're configured to crash on unobserved, throw the exception.
// We need to publish the event above even if we're not going to crash, hence
// why this check doesn't come at the beginning of the method.
if (s_failFastOnUnobservedException && !ueea.m_observed)
{
    throw exceptionToThrow;
}
```

とあり、`s_failFastOnUnobservedException`変数はApp.configの値から設定されます。ファイナライザースレッドで投げられた例外は処理できずにプロセスが停止されるのでしょう。

それに対し、[.NET 5.0.0の`TaskExceptionHolder`ファイナライザー](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskExceptionHolder.cs#L51-L70)は

```
~TaskExceptionHolder()
{
    if (m_faultExceptions != null && !m_isHandled)
    {
        // We will only propagate if this is truly unhandled. The reason this could
        // ever occur is somewhat subtle: if a Task's exceptions are observed in some
        // other finalizer, and the Task was finalized before the holder, the holder
        // will have been marked as handled before even getting here.

        // Publish the unobserved exception and allow users to observe it
        AggregateException exceptionToThrow = new AggregateException(
            SR.TaskExceptionHolder_UnhandledException,
            m_faultExceptions);
        UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs ueea = new UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs(exceptionToThrow);
        TaskScheduler.PublishUnobservedTaskException(m_task, ueea);
    }
}
```

ときれいさっぱり整理されています。

---

プロセスを終了させたいのであれば、[`<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions>`要素の解説](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/throwunobservedtaskexceptions-element#remarks)にもあるように[`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`イベント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=net-6.0)からプロセスを終了すればいいのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 詳細ありがとうございます。.NET6では対応してないようですね。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration に「.NET 5 以降 (および .NET Core) の App.config ファイルは、ランタイム構成に使用されなくなりました。 App.config ファイルにこれらのセクションが含まれている場合、それらは考慮されません。」という記述も見つけました。runtimeセクション自体が機能してなさそうです。

Comment: TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException からさらに例外を throw することで同様の挙動にすることができました。